# SQL Server 2014 Management Studio Does Not Show Database Diagrams Folder

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, diagram

I have two servers. One is from a cloud. The other is local, in which I created using a series of SQL commands (that someone else wrote).

I want to create a database diagram, but the Database Diagram node won't show in either database that I want it to (in this case IMDB_copy from cloud server, and master from local server). However, for some reason it's showing up on my local ReportServer database which is of no use to me.

Here is a link to the image: http://postimg.org/image/7qi84sblx/

I am running Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Management Studio on Windows 10.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I accidentally created the tables via a query in master, rather the creating a new database and creating the tables in that. Oops. The database diagrams doesn't show up in master obviously.